# Вывод таблицы из БД с помощью своего плагина PHP на свою wordpress страницу

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wordpress-плагины

Работаю на локальном сервере xampp. Пытаюсь написать свой плагин для wordpress для своей локальной страницы. В phpMyAdmin создал бд и в ней таблицу. Нужно вывести данные этой таблицы на wordpress странице. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
function TD()
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'wordpress');
    $query = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM info_domen');

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    if($result)
    {
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // количество полученных строк

        echo "<table><tr><th>Id</th><th>Модель</th><th>Производитель</th></tr>";
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
        {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            echo "<tr>";
            for ($j = 0 ; $j < 3 ; ++$j) echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        // очищаем результат
        mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Не понятно как привязать это к wordpress странице. Через шорткод не выйдет, так как используется echo. Нужно цеплять к каким то хукам? подскажите.

Comment: просто ужасно. Ваш код и wordpress на разных полюсах

Comment: у вп вроде бы есть свои функции для выборки из БД

Comment: Что такое "локальная страница"?

Answer (score 2):

Всё неправильно. Абсолютно всё.

Во первых с базой так работать нельзя. Для работы с базой у ВП есть специальный класс [wpdb](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb). Но это нужно только в особых случаях, и скорее всего тут не нужно.

Во вторых есть [шаблоны](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2), которые отвечают за вывод отдельных типов страниц.

В третьих есть [кастомные поля](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F) и [кастомные типы](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/),  с пом. которых скорее всего и надо решать поставленную задачу.

В общем, чтобы не подставлять клиента надо отдать проект специалисту по ВП.